# Nodal Analysis #1 - Where is my mistake?

Tags: circuit-analysis, analysis, circuit-theory

I am given a problem with its shallow solution (i.e. not all steps/formulas shown). When I tackled the problem (below), my answer didn't match the apparently correct solution. Where is my mistake? The bold writing is the apparent "correct" answer.

[image: Attempt at problem in question.]

Comment: Show the material in the question - links can die...

Comment: Image was over 2MB, I feared the writing wouldn't be readable if I resized it smaller...

Comment: All current directions and nodes were labeled/chosen by me, aside from current Io, which is what the problem asks for.

Comment: I think I7 equation has a wrong sign ... can't see it very clearly

Comment: I7=-jVe + jVc  ?

Comment: Yes, I7 should be -j*VE + j*VC (I had written -j*VE - j*VC). However, I just re-solved it, and this only changes VE in the Solution matrix of node voltages from 2+j14 to 2+j10. The final answer is dependent on VC, though, not VE.

Comment: You could reduce the size of the matrices by using VE=VB+6, and re-work. That might get rid of the lurking error. Also, as a general rule, I find that summing currents away from a node and equating to zero is less error prone.